# Eigen not found when using FetchContent

Tags: c++, eigen, fetchcontent

I am attempting to include the Eigen libraries into my project.

I am using CMake and FetchContent to build the project. I was able to include another library using the same method.

A snippit of my "dependencies.cmake" is included below:

```
if (NOT TARGET endftk )
           FetchContent_Declare( endftk
           GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/njoy/ENDFtk.git
           GIT_TAG origin/develop )
           FetchContent_MakeAvailable( endftk)
endif()

if (NOT TARGET Eigen)
        FetchContent_Declare( Eigen
        GIT_REPOSITORY  https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
        GIT_TAG origin/master )
        FetchContent_MakeAvailable( Eigen)
endif()
```

I link both libraries using:

```
 target_link_libraries(POLR
               INTERFACE ENDFtk
               INTERFACE eigen )
```

in my main header file I then include the libraries using:

```
#include <ENDFtk.hpp>
#include <Eigen>
```

I've also tried using the following:

```
#include <Eigen3>
#include <eigen> 
#include <Eigen.hpp>
```

All of which fail with the following error message when attempting to make:

```
fatal error: Eigen: No such file or directory
```

However, I have no such issue including and using the ENDFtk library.

I've looked in my `build/_deps` folder and I do see Eigen (and ENDFtk) there.

Does anybody know what I need to do in order to get Eigen to include?

I'm using:
cmake version 3.22.1
gcc version 11.3.0

Please let me know if there is any crucial information I'm leaving out.

Note: POLR is the name of my project.

Comment: Should `FetchContent_MakeAvailable( endftk)` be `FetchContent_MakeAvailable( Eigen)`? And in your source code you should write `#include <Eigen/Core>` etc (`#include <Eigen/Eigen>` if you want to include everything).

Comment: That was a mistake in my question, thank you for catching it. My code does read 
FetchContent_MakeAvailable( Eigen) 

I've also tried #include <Eigen/Dense> 
It doesn't seem to find the package at all

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? (Remove everything not related to Eigen then post your complete CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp file)